# Visibility of bottomsheet for only certain tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, position

Is there a way that an Exhibitionbottomsheet is visible only when the user is on a specified tab and not for other tabs.

The code-

```
Tabs(refresh: () => setState(() {})),
                value == 0 ? Center(child: AboutPage()) : Container(),
                value == 1 ? Center(child: Sliding()) : Container(),
                value == 2 ? Center(child: CoveragePage()) : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ExhibitionBottomSheet()
```

In the above code the ExhibitionBottomSheet() is visible for all the tabs, but if it can only be visible for Sliding() then it would be better.So is there any way we can do that?

I tried calling the ExhibitionBottomSheet() in the Sliding() card itself and not for all tabs but as all the three tabs are sizedBox's it's showing a positioning error but works fine when  called it in below the tabs as you all can see.
The ExhibitionBottomSheet() is an Expandable bottom widget.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to this would be to render it only if the correct tab is selected like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Tabs(/* as before */),
    if(value == 1)
      ...[ExhibitionBottomSheet()]
  ],
),
```

This the bottom sheet will only get shown if the second tab is active.

Comment: Tried Adding this but it gives error line on ExhibitionBottotmSheet().The code- Tabs(refresh: () => setState(() {})),
                value == 0 ? Center(child: AboutPage()) : Container(),
                value == 1 ? Center(child: AdilabadB1Sliding()) : Container(),
                value == 2 ? Center(child: CoveragePage()) : Container(),
                value == 3 ? Center(child: CoveragePage()) : Container(),
                if(value ==1)[ExhibitionBottomSheet()]